# Twilio: Where to upload an audio file

Tags: twilio

On this Twilio page: https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223180588-Best-Practices-for-Audio-Recordings

It talks about uploading an audio file to twilio and allowing twilio to do the audio conversion.  I have not found a way to upload the file on the website. Where is this done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

That is a slightly misleading article and I apologise. There's no direct way to upload audio files to Twilio. However, when you use the [`<Play>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/play) verb in TwiML that points to the location of an audio file then technically it will get uploaded to Twilio and converted as that article describes.

When using `<Play>` you do need to host the original audio file somewhere online first.

**Update**

There is now a way to upload assets to Twilio so that they can be used with `<Play>`. Check out the documentation on [Twilio Assets here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/assets).

Comment: Is it the same with the Twilio studio?

Comment: @GerardoJaramillo Yes, you still need to upload your mp3 files somewhere first. Good news is that you can do that in Twilio now, with [Twilio Assets](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/assets).

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I can confirm I did it, and it works great!